# Template argument substitution fails if I use std::string in decltype

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

After debugging some (much more complicated) template code (where I'm using SFINAE to only execute a function if a specific class constructor exists) and being unable to understand the error, I made a minimal example, and I can't seem to figure out how this makes sense.

Minimal (or smallest I could come up with) example:

```
#include <string>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::string s, int i){}
};

template<typename>
struct int_ {
    typedef int type;
};

template<typename U, typename int_<decltype(U("", 0))>::type = 0>
void fun(){}

int main() {
    fun<MyClass>();
    return 0;
}
```

^ this is fully functional and behaves exactly as I want
but if I change line 13 from

```
template<typename U, typename int_<decltype(U("", 0))>::type = 0>
```

to

```
template<typename U, typename int_<decltype(U(std::string(), 0))>::type = 0>
```

I get a substitution failure. (it also fails with `declval<std::string>()` among others)

If it just couldn't convert between two types hidden somewhere deep in `std::` I'd still be combing documentation, but I don't even know where to start mainly because the error is unexpected (at least to me)

```
no matching function for call to 'MyClass::MyClass(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)'
```

and

```
no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'int'
```

are the relevant parts (to me being confused, if other parts may be relevant [here is a link to cpp.sh with the failing code](http://cpp.sh/6ew3k))

as far as I can tell, somehow `std::string` overrides any subsequent types but the number of arguments stays the same.  it does this even if there are more than 2 template arguments (the code I'm actually using this in had 4, and it said I had passed in `std::string` for all 4 arguments)

Am I making a dumb mistake?  I just can't figure out why this is happening, and why using a `char *` fixes it.

Comment: It compiles in Clang and [GCC trunk](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GLfH9dJGVHVkYPzO). It seems this was a GCC bug that has been fixed. A simple workaround is to change the outer parenthesis to braces `U(...) -> U{...}`

Comment: @0x499602D2 oh okay! thanks!